# Want to add new items below the existing items using inverted flatlist like live Streaming comment section in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-flatlist

I am using inverted Flatlist , here i want to add new comments below the existing comments exactly like Live Streaming comment section.I am using here inverted Flatlist but the new comments are added above the existing comments Please help me what to do here?

Comment: you just have to sort the data in the order you want to show.

Comment: let newArr =[...oldArr, ...newCommentsArr]
 // or the other way around if you want to reverse it :
 [...newCommentsArr, ...oldArr]

Comment: here i just push one upon another item to the inverted flatlist, but newly pushed item appear at the above of the existing but i want newly item pushed below the existing...here how to sort or what is to be sort ...not understand?

Comment: Actually here dynamically comments are added no items to sort here ...added comments are to be added as like live streaming comment sections are showing..please help i am using here inverted flatlist

Comment: use flexDirection:'column-reverse' if you are using inverted Flatlist

Comment: i solve it .when pushing one upon another object into the main array which is used in flatlist ..instead the .push() method .unshift() method ...and use inverted Flatlist, it will solve my issue...